# (Integer) Variant of Hilbert’s irreducibility theorem

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, arithmetic

Let $P\in{\mathbb Q}[X,Y]$ such that $P(x,.)$ has an integer root for any integer 
$x\in{\mathbb Z}$. Does it follow that $P$ has factors of the form
$Y-Q(X)$ for some $Q\in{\mathbb Q}[X]$, and does it follow also that if we denote
by $Q_1,Q_2, \ldots ,Q_r$ the polynomials that arise in this way in the factorisation of $P$, then for any $x\in{\mathbb Z}$ at least one of the $Q_i(x)$ is an integer.

Comment: @Cantlog Thanks for your correction, I updated the post.

Comment: Then what about  $(Y-X/2)(Y-(X+1)/2)$ ?

Comment: Using a strong form of Hilbert's irreducibility theorem, you can show that $P$ has a factor of the form $Y-Q(X)$ with $Q(X)\in \mathbb Q[X]$, but I don't know what to say about $Q(X)$.

Comment: @Cantlog Indeed, that “strong form” (due to Cohen) is shown on an article that’s freely available online, it appeared in a recent other MSE question, and probably completely answers this question, but I have been too busy with other things lately to update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rewrite the answer to include the first question** (for the sake of completeness and for my own record).

(I). Yes, $P(X,Y)$ has a factor of the form $Y-Q(X)$ with $Q(X)\in \mathbb Q[x]$.

Decompose $P$ into 
$$P(X,Y)=(\prod_{1\le i\le r}(Y-Q_i(X))\prod_j P_j(X,Y)$$ with $\deg_Y(P_j)\ge 2$ (for the moment, $r$ could be zero). For $N$ big enough, by the strong version of Hilbert irreducibility theorem, the set of $k\in \mathbb Z$ such that $|k|\le N$ and one of the $P_j(k, Y)$ has a zero in $\mathbb Z$ (thus is reducible) has cardinality $\le c\sqrt{N}$ for some absolute constant $c$ 
(see the link given by Ewan in his answer, or [this paper of M. Fried](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/2027.42/22343/1/0000789.pdf) in a less general setting, but enough for our purpose). 
As $P(k, Y)$ has a root in $\mathbb Z$ for any $k=-N, -(N-1), ..., N$, taking $N>c^2/4$, we see that $r\ge 1$. This answers the first question.

(II). The answer is also yes.

Write $Q_i(X)=F_i(X)/d$ with $F_i(X)\in \mathbb Z[X]$ and $d\in \mathbb N$. Let $k\in\mathbb Z$. Then 
$$Q_i(k)\in \mathbb Z\Longleftrightarrow \ d \mid F_i(k) \ \Longleftrightarrow F_i(k) \equiv 0 \mod d.$$ 
If $S_i\subset \mathbb Z$ is a set of representatives of the zeros of $F_i(X)$ in $\mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z$, then $Q_i(k)\in \mathbb Z$ for some $i\le r$ if and only if 
$$k\in \cup_{1\le i\le r} (S_i+d\mathbb Z)=(\cup_{1\le i\le r} S_i)+d\mathbb Z.$$ 
We saw above that the set of $k\in \mathbb Z$ such that $|k|\le N$ and one of the $P_j(k, Y)$ has a zero in $\mathbb Z$ has cardinality $\le c\sqrt{N}$. The cardinality of those $k$ such that one of the $Y-Q_i(k)$ has a zero in $\mathbb Z$ (equivalently $Q_i(k)\in\mathbb Z$) is about $2sN/d$, where $s$ is the cardinality of $\cup_i S_i$. As the union of these two types of $k$ has $2N+1$ elements, this forces $s=d$, hence $(\cup_i S_i)+d\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z$ and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

The strengthening of Hilbert’s irreducibility theorem  in  Cohen’s [article](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=628276) (thanks to David Speyer for drawing attention to this article in his answer to this other MSE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497569/a-low-degree-polynomial-g-a-bx-which-has-a-zero-x-in-mathbb-n-for-any-sq)) shows that the answer is YES to the first part of the question.
  The second part remains to be seen.